# How to store the output of huffman coding to a binary file in binary format instead of ASCii format

Tags: c++, vector, huffman-code

After encoding a string I've got an output like below from Huffman coding and stored each bit in boolean array.

{00100100100100000000010001000100000101010101010101000010000111}

Now I'm trying to write each bit to .bin file in binary format instead of writing ASCII characters.
However,I read some questions on stack overflow site and many of them were mentioned to use vector or to do some bits shifting operations.I tried first option by storing each bit in a vector,but I cannot figure out a way to write content of vector to a .bin file because it gives an error like this "taking address of temporary -fpermissive".According to the error I've an idea I may messed up dealing with pointers and I don't know much about how bit shifting works.
So,Could someone give me a step by step description or a source code about how to store above output in binary format in a .bin file?For ex: 16 bits store as 2 bytes.I am expecting the answer in c++

```
Vector<bool> bits; 

ofstream data; 
data.open("file.bin",ios::out|ios::binary); 
size_t size = bits.size();

 for (int  i=0; i < size; i++) 
{

      data.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bits[i],sizeof(bool))); 

} 

data.close();
```

This is the code I have used to write the content of vector to a binary file.I need above bits array in actual byte not in ascii

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want your file to contain the ascii representations for `'0'` and `'1'`, or the actual bytes? I also noticed your boolean array has 62 bits, which is not divisible by 8. How do you want your final byte to appear in this case? Please show the code you have used for this task (even if it didn't work how you want) so we can see what part you're getting tripped up on.

Comment: Vector<bool> bits;
ofstream data;
    data.open("file.bin",ios::out|ios::binary);
    size_t size = bits.size();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        data.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bits[i],sizeof(bool)));
    }
    data.close();
This is the code I have used to write the content of vector to a binary file.
I know I have to use padding bits with 62bits to be dividable by 8.
I need the above array of bits in bytes.not in ASCII.

Comment: Please edit your question itself with new information, don't add it in comments. One issue is that the comments can't be formatted nicely like questions can.

Comment: What's `Vector`?

Comment: I didn't understand your question.I guess you asked what type of vector I used which is boolean.As above code I used bits(variable name) vector to put all bits and if I'm wrong correct me.

Comment: Are you using `std::vector` or a special class called `Vector`? Make sure the code you post is the actual code you are trying to use.

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` has its bits stored in an implementation defined manner, and there's no guarantee that you can just just copy from `&bits[0]` into the file.

Comment: I'm using #include <vector> with name space std.

Comment: If so,are there any alternative way to copy bits to the file.?